# Shibboleth SP to point to multiple idP

Tags: single-sign-on, shibboleth, opensaml

I have SP installed on a machine.
I need to have it configured to multiple idP depending upon the url.

Ex.
We have two hosts `one.myorg.com` and `two.myorg.com` both point to same module/machine - so same SP.

Now I need my sp configured as if `one.myorg.com/secure` is hit SP should go to `https://testshib.com/idp` for authentication and else `two.myorg.com/secure` is hit SP should go to `https://myown.idp.com` idp.

EDIT: It should not ask to choose the idP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case this is still actual, you can find some hints <del>here: https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/IdPDiscovery.</del> on the Shibboleth Wiki [here](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/CONCEPT/IdPDiscovery).

The key idea is to provide a entityID to the IdP in question in a manually crafted login request to the SP login module, like

```
https://sp.testshib.org/Shibboleth.sso/TestShib?entityID=https%3A%2F%2Fidp.testshib.org%2Fidp%2Fshibboleth
```

where `entityID=...` is the url-encoded entityID of the IdP in question.

The documentation of this parameter can be found [on the Shibboleth Wiki](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPSessionInitiator#NativeSPSessionInitiator-TypesofSessionInitiators) in the "Advanced configuration" section.

Comment: However some of the links are changed. http://stackoverflow.com/a/42711862/1534925 this is the answer from working links.