# Shibboleth- Auto Choose from multiple idp based on Url for single SP

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, shibboleth

We are using Shibboleth Service provider  for our application. We have installed the Sp in our local machine.
Now I need to have it configured to multiple idP depending upon the url. 
Example:
 We have two hosts one.sample.com and two.sample.com both point to same machine - so same SP.

So want to  configure Sp in way that when hit one.sample.com then it authenticate user using https://testshib.com/idp and when hit two.sample.com then authenticate user with another idp.

It should not ask me to choose the idP. it should automatically identify idp based on the host Url.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shibboleth SP to point to multiple idP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21858019/shibboleth-sp-to-point-to-multiple-idp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `<RequestMap>` element in `shibboleth2.xml` file.

More details can be found [here](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPRequestMap).

> ```
> <RequestMap applicationId="default">
>     <Host name="www.example.org">
>         <Path name="secure" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true"/>
>     </Host>
>     <Host name="admin.example.org" applicationId="admin" authType="shibboleth" requireSession="true">
>         <AccessControl>
>             <Rule require="affiliation">faculty@osu.edu student@osu.edu</Rule>
>         </AccessControl>
>     </Host> </RequestMap>
> ```

Above exmple is directly taken from the Shibboleth wiki link I provided above.

You can ignore AccessControl tag if you want and map Host and Path directly. So for your example, you will need to create two applications and map two host to application. If you don't provide applicationId then it will take `ApplicationDefault` as application.

How to provide multiple application can be found [here](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/SHIB2/NativeSPApplication).

Comment: But Host is not limited in our case it can one.sample.com ,two.sample.com,three.sample.com and upto n numbers of hosts and each host point to  same directory.
Do  i need to  create applications on IIS for every  host ?

Comment: So you provide n number of `host` element in this file. It can not be done so simply if your hosts are in multiplication of 10 or dynamic

Comment: How will the urls(hosts) map on different idp ?

Comment: YOu need to create multiple applications, basically there will be one application defaults and inside that multiple applications. All the applications will have id. You need to map hosts to that respective Ids.